# example.com is OK for domain example, what is example IP Address?

Tags: network-programming, ip-address

We use the example.com often for domain name reference. I wonder if any IP address used as an example IP address to mention in references like tutorial or notes?. I knew the loop back interface 127.0.0.1 can be used but it has been known for local system always.

Can example.com IP Address used for this purpose legally?

Comment: You can actually open the URL https://example.com/ for more information about this.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

From [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737)

> The blocks 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1),
> 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2),    and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3) are provided for use in    documentation.

---

From [RFC 3849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3849.html)

> IANA is to record the allocation of the IPv6 global unicast address
> prefix 2001:DB8::/32 as a documentation-only prefix in the IPv6
> address registry. No end party is to be assigned this address.

Answer (score 29):

There is no law against (ab)using someone elses domain or IP address in examples, but it is a very bad idea. As some users will use your example values verbatim.
For example, the IP address `1.2.3.4` have been used in examples.  But that is live real IPv4 addresses that are used in `1/8` as valid global IPv4-prefix. There are already some concerns about this use of that address in examples.

[RFC5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737) is about IPv4 addresses used for examples, which are any address in networks `192.0.2.0/24` (`TEST-NET-1`), `198.51.100.0/24` (`TEST-NET-2`) and `203.0.113.0/24` (`TEST-NET-3`), like `192.0.2.10`, `198.51.100.3` or `203.0.113.254`.  These doesn't exist on Internet.

> Three IPv4 unicast address blocks are reserved for use in examples in
> specifications and other documents.  This document describes the use
> of these blocks.

[RFC3849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3849) is about IPv6 addresses used for examples, which are any address in `2001:db8::/32`. These are are also not used on Internet.

> The document describes the use of the IPv6
> address prefix `2001:DB8::/32` as a reserved prefix for use in
> documentation.

[RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) is about reserved TLD:s for different use.  Those are "`.test`", "`.example`", "`.invalid`" and "`localhost`". Any domain under those can be used, like "`a-host.example`"
"`test`" is used for testing, "`example`" for documentation, "`invalid`" in configuration files that needs to be tweeked and "`localhost`" for `127/8` (mostly `127.0.0.1`).  There are also three reserved second level domains to be used for example domains (`example.com`, `example.net` and `example.org`).

> To reduce the likelihood of conflict and confusion, a few top level
> domain names are reserved for use in private testing, as examples in
> documentation, and the like.  In addition, a few second level domain
> names reserved for use as examples are documented.

[RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) is about the private network addresses `10/8`, `172.16/12` and `192.168/16`. Those are private and should not exist on Internet, so they might be used for example networks. But it's better to use the other reserved IP addresses mentioned above, as they will not conflict with real private network use in users LAN setup.

> This document describes address allocation for private internets. The
> allocation permits full network layer connectivity among all hosts
> inside an enterprise as well as among all public hosts of different
> enterprises.

[RFC3330](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330) should be of interest as an overview of all special IPv4 networks.

> This document describes the global and other specialized IPv4 address
> blocks that have been assigned by the Internet Assigned Numbers
> Authority (IANA).

Comment: "There is no law against abusing someone elses domain or IP address in examples, but it is a very bad idea." Not that I'm arguing with you, but can you explain why it's such a bad idea?

Comment: Because people will use the values in your example configuration and documentation, even if you tell them not to. Especially if your configs/docs get used and read.  That is why there are IP addresses and domains explicitly reserved for use in example configuration files and in documentations.

Comment: I understand that aspect, I'm just wondering if there are any kind of legal ramifications.

Comment: No, not what I know.  Not where I am from anyway.

Comment: How can I try this like hosting in any other server you are saying? any source or tutorial

Comment: There may well be legal consequences. While there may not be an *explicit* law against it, there are laws that apply in case of damage. For example, if you use a real IP in an example and publish the example, knowing that it will likely attract many users, knowing that you cannot expect users to replace the example IP, and suddenly a service goes down because of that, you may be sued for gross negligence. Whether or not the trial would be successful, just the amount of time and stress, especially if you have to pay a legal counsel to defend yourself, may not be worth it. (no legal advice)

Answer (score 1):

> Can example.com IP Address used for this purpose legally?

Any IP address can be used as an example legally - there's no law that would prevent you from doing that. Using one of the [private ranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) or an invalid one (making any of the four numbers greater than 255) will prevent anyone accidentally flooding someone's IP with an infinite loop or something based off your examples.

Comment: Or use the reserved example IP nets and domains. Then you will have a valid, but unusable configuration I'd your examples and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using it for an example in documentation, pick an IP address that isn't technically valid (like 192.168.0.256).  It still conveys the point, but you don't have to worry about it being in use.

Comment: Or better yet, use the example IP nets and domains.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use one of the private ranges, e.g. 192.168.1.1.  I wouldn't use anyone's public IP space.

Comment: This range are ok, but are bad as it still can interfere with someones real configurations. Please use the reserved IP ranges instead. They are not used for anything else then examples and documentation.

Answer (score -4):

This would have similar use to the phone numbers in movies starting with 555-...

IP 1.2.3.4 appears to be too synthetic. Maybe you can use www.icann.org ( 192.0.32.7 ), or tempuri.org ( 207.46.197.32 ).

Comment: There are special nets and domains to be used in example configurations and documentation. Use them.