# httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I tried to restart my Apache server on CentOS 5.0 and got this message:

> httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

Here is the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1    server4-245    server4-245.com    localhost.localdomain localhost
::1        localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Here is the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file:

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=server4-245
```

I also have this in the Apache httpd.conf file:

```
ServerName localhost
```

However, I still get the first error message when I restart Apache.

Comment: Ensure you edited the right `httpd.conf`. Usually `ServerName xy` is just fine.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Your hosts file does not include a valid FQDN, nor is `localhost` an FQDN. An FQDN must include a hostname part, as well as a domain name part. For example, the following is a valid FQDN:

```
host.server4-245.com
```

Choose an FQDN and include it both in your `/etc/hosts` file on both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses you are using (in your case, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`), and change your `ServerName` in your httpd configuration to match.

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost host.server4-245.com
::1          localhost.localdomain localhost host.server4-245.com
```

httpd.conf:

```
ServerName host.server4-245.com
```

Comment: Note too that you'll want to modify your HOSTNAME entry in your /etc/sysconfig/network file to match your chosen name.

Comment: Hmm. I've got: 
`127.0.0.1       localhost gondor gondor.localdomain
192.168.0.3     gondor.localdomain` 
but it seems linux doesn't think that gondor.localdomain is an FQDN either. What's the issue with that? Do I have to have a TLD?

Comment: Hi I did try all of the above and I am still getting the same errors, I don't quite understand what I lack here. My FQDN is ak.local.com set in the same fashion as your answer but I am still getting the same issues.
I am running on OSX 10.10

Comment: I found that:
127.0.0.1 myserver myserver.mydom.com ... etc << does not work
127.0.0.1 myserver.mydom.com myserver ... etc << does work

Comment: As @Martin noticed, the FQN should be the _first_ name in each line in `/e/hosts` after the IP address.  _Then_ you add the aliases, like the name without domain name, and other names that could be useful.

You can always check the result with the command `getent hosts _IP-number/hostname_` to see what programs will see. It uses the same mechanism that C-programs uses (most programs).  Could also try `ahosts` instead of `hosts`.  See man pages for `getent(1)`. *Very* useful program for any administrator.

Answer (score 216):

If you don't have `httpd.conf` in folder `/etc/apache2`, you should have apache2.conf - simply add:

> ServerName localhost

Then restart the `apache2` service.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running multiple virtual hosts.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Mac OS 10.7.5 running multiple virtual hosts.

Comment: Worked on Mac OS 10.7.5 running Virtualbox

Comment: Worked perfectly on Centos 6.4.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Centos 6 (cloud version), though httpd.conf was in /etc/httpd/conf/

Comment: Worked perfectly on RHEL 6.2

Comment: Worked perfectly on Linux Mint 16 :)

Comment: This caused redirection problems with virtual hosts for me. I have a default vhost that deals with spoof domain access and non-canonical access (e.g. to strip the www. off) which does not use `ServerName` (as per docs for the default vhost), but putting this in seemed to confuse it mightily.

Comment: Worked on Centos 6.6.

Comment: On Dockerised Centos 6.4 had to use ServerName ${HOSTNAME}

Comment: Worked perfectly on openSUSE Leap.

Comment: thanks worked for macOs m1 bigsur

Comment: Actually, this _might_ work OK today in Debian based distributions, like Ubuntu. It certainly worked back in 2013. 
But now we uses `a2en*` and `a2di*` commands. And they make links from `/e/a2/conf-available` to `e/a2/conf-enable`. So you edit files in `/e/a2/conf-available` and the server looks for enable ones in `/e/a2/conf-enable`.  Same for `mod`-file etc.  
If you use other popular web servers, they use a similar mechanism on Debian based distributions. (Easier to copy and remove files/links then edit one huge one)

Comment: Worked perfectly on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 67):

After the initial install of Apache server, I got the following error while restarting the Apache service on [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin)

The solution is really simple. Just add the `ServerName` directive to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Add: `ServerName  localhost`

Finally restart the Apache server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Within CentOS 7, the path will be /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Debian based distributions uses one configuration file per virtual server in Apache2. That is `/etc/apache2/conf-available` and `/etc/apache2/conf-enable` tells which is available and which is enable. 
You also uses commands lie `a2ensite webs` to enable `webs`-webserver via `/e/a/c-a/webs.conf`. See `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz` (use `zcat`) for more `a2en*` and `a2di*` commands.

Comment: But obviously this isn't valid on RedHat based Linux distributions. :-)
Just added for Debian based distribution users to find the right source and instructions.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you're editing the right `httpd.conf` file, then the error about unreliable server's domain name should be gone (this is the most common mistake).

To locate your `httpd.conf` Apache configuration file, run:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Then edit the file and uncomment or change `ServerName` line into:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Then restart your apache by: `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: "Make sure you're editing the right htttpd.conf file," this helped me on macOS. I wasn't editing the right `http.conf`file. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this answer saved me after long time seeking answer!

Answer (score 11):

So while this is answered and accepted it still came up as a top search result and the answers though laid out (after lots of research) left me scratching my head and digging a lot further. So here's a quick layout of how I resolved the issue.

Assuming my server is myserver.myhome.com and my static IP address is 192.168.1.150:

1. Edit the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

   ```
   $ sudo nano -w /etc/hosts

   127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

   127.0.0.1 myserver.myhome.com myserver

   192.168.1.150 myserver.myhome.com myserver

   ::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
   ::1 myserver.myhome.com myserver
   ```
2. Edit httpd.conf

   ```
   $ sudo nano -w /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

   ServerName myserver.myhome.com
   ```
3. Edit network

   ```
   $ sudo nano -w /etc/sysconfig/network HOSTNAME=myserver.myhome.com
   ```
4. Verify

   ```
   $ hostname

   (output) myserver.myhome.com

   $ hostname -f

   (output) myserver.myhome.com
   ```
5. Restart Apache

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

It appeared the difference was including `myserver.myhome.com` to both the 127.0.0.1 as well as the static IP address 192.168.1.150 in the hosts file. The same on Ubuntu Server and CentOS.

Answer (score 9):

In httpd.conf, search for "ServerName". It's usually commented out by default on Mac. Just uncomment it and fill it in. Make sure you also have the name/ip combo set in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  httpd wasn't picking up my fqdn in /etc/hosts, and my hostname seemed configured properly.

Answer (score 4):

In the Apache `httpd.conf` file:

```
ServerName: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to resolve this error:

1. `Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

   Add the above line in file **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**
2. Add this line at the end of the file **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**:

   **ServerName localhost**

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved the fully qualified domain name message on different occasions by adding my server hostname to the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file and to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

Type `hostname -f` in your terminal.  This query will return your hostname.

Then edit the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file (or create it if it does not exist for some reason) and add `ServerName <your_hostname>`.

Alternatively, I have also been able to eliminate the message by adding `ServerName <your_hostname>` to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

If all goes well, when you restart Apache, the message will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers suggest to just add `ServerName localhost` to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

But quoting [Apache documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotDetermineServerName) :

> The presence of this error message also indicates that Apache httpd was unable to obtain a fully-qualified hostname by doing a reverse lookup on your server's IP address. While the above instructions will get rid of the warning in any case, it is also a good idea to fix your name resolution so that this reverse mapping works.

Therefore adding such a line to `/etc/hosts` is probably a more robust solution :

```
192.0.2.0  foobar.example.com  foobar
```

where [192.0.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151552/812102) is the static IP address of the server named `foobar` within the `example.com` domain.

One can check the FQDN e.g. with

```
hostname -A
```

(shortcut for `hostname --all-fqdn`).

Comment: To look up names, like any program does, you could also run this on Linux machines `getent hosts hostname` or `getent hosts 192.0.20.0`.  If you want all IP addresses, not just IPv6, try `getent ahost 192.0.20.0`.
This uses the same API as C programs uses (that is most programs).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I had this problem and it was because I used "tabs" to indent lines instead of spaces.  Just posting, in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you've edited `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` with the `ServerName localhost` you may be editing the wrong file. All answers I found were pointing towards that standard httpd.conf. After some foraging, I found a good answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401852).

To locate the right httpd.conf file use

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

I found mine was actually `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`.

Use your preferred editor to comment out the line (i.e. remove the `#` before) starting with ServerName, and replace the domain name for the appropriate one – local environments should work with

```
ServerName localhost
```

I hope this helps more people who may be stuck.