# restart the apache server though putty

Tags: apache

I am new in linux. I have the server details. I am accessing this server through putty. I want to restart the server. After login the server I typed " sudo apachectl restart" after that it asked the password and after giving that I got "apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 202.136.40.61 for ServerName". For kind information,I have not the superuser's password. So shall I restart the server?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a warning and tells you that your system is not configured properly. Nevertheless apache should have been restarted.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541460/httpd-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-us) for a solution to the warning, but you probably won't be able to fix it anyway without super user privileges.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```