# Mountain Lion apache vhost

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion

Trying to setup vhost and unsure what I am doing wrong. If I run apachectl, I get this warning.

```
$ sudo apachectl -t
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Johns-MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName
[Tue Apr 16 21:34:01 2013] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
Syntax OK
```

So whats happening is everything is reverting to the top vhost. Here is my vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jcostanzo/development/impress"
    ServerName impress.local
    ServerAlias impress.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/impress.local-error_log"

    <Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/development/impress" >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jcostanzo/development/testsomething"
    ServerName testing.local
    ServerAlias testing.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.local-error_log"

    <Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/development/testsomething" >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first warning

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Johns-MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName
```

you get, because you didn't define the server name yet. Easily define it in /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Than your hostname is localhost and you won't get this warning anymore. Some more information is here: [httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541460/httpd-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-us)

The second warning:

```
[Tue Apr 16 21:34:01 2013] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

probably appears because you are missing

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

in your vhosts file. Did you edit the standard

```
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

file? It's also little bit strange that you take the same URL for

```
ServerAlias
```

as for the

```
ServerName
```

Try again with this configuration and it should work:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName impress.local
    ServerAlias www.impress.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jcostanzo/development/impress"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/impress.local-error_log"
    <Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/development/impress" >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testing.local
    ServerAlias www.testing.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jcostanzo/development/testsomething"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.local-error_log"
    <Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/development/testsomething" >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Run

```
apachectl -S
```

to see, if apache accepts your configuration.