# Getting apache started

Tags: apache

when i hit

```
httpd.exe -k start
```

from cmd line I'm getting error like this:

> AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::691f:cf01:4df3:a6c3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

any ideas how to fix this?

//edit 
I have added Server name as follows to httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost
```

Now when I hit

```
 httpd.exe -k start
```

I can see no errors, but when I try to start the apache2.4 service via Apache SErvice Monitor I'm getting error "The requested operation has failed!"

this is the log from error.log

```
[Tue Oct 25 17:33:35.602716 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 1316:tid 296] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00378: Failed to start the 'Apache2.4' service
```

Comment: It says it in the message: Set the ServerName in the httpd.conf. Note that this is a warning, not an error message, and apache will still start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541460/httpd-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-us)